# How to either sort a wxsizer or remove items without destroying them?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a wxpython grid sizer that is sizing sublists of bitmap buttons. The master list I would like to create just once because creating these buttons takes a considerable amount of time, and thus I do not want to destroy them.  My idea is to somehow remove all of the buttons from the sizer, make a new list of the buttons that I want the sizer to contain, and then use the sizer's AddMany method.

If I can't remove the buttons from the sizer without destroying them, then is there a way to use the sizer's Show method to hide some of the times, but then have the sizer adjust to fill in the gaps?  When I hide them, all I can get them to do right now is just to have them disappear and leave a gap.  I need the next item to be adjusted to the gap's place.

Also is there a way to sort the grid sizer's item list?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sort the sizer items in place. It would be possible to write your own function for doing this, of course, but it would use `wxSizer::Detach()` and `Insert()` under the hood anyhow.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.  Took me a while to realize though that before I detached the items I needed to hide them, or else they would stay visible yet unaffected by the sizer.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that the detach method is what I'm looking for! I would still be interested to know of a way to sort a sizer's item list though, without detaching all of the items and then re attaching a sublist.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the Layout method on the parent of the sizer, this will make it recalculate the shown items.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the buttons to sort is a little tricky, but the key is finding something to sort by. You could use the button label or the button name. I went with the latter. The following code also demonstrates how to show/hide buttons:

```
import random
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        for item in range(10):
            val = random.choice(range(10000,99999))
            label = "Button %s" % val
            name = "btn%s" % val
            btn = wx.Button(self, label=label, name=name)
            self.mainSizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)

        toggleBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Hide/Show Some Buttons")
        toggleBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onHideShow)
        hSizer.Add(toggleBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        sortBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Sort buttons")
        sortBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSort)
        hSizer.Add(sortBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.mainSizer.Add(hSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onHideShow(self, event):
        """
        Hide / Show the buttons
        """
        children = self.mainSizer.GetChildren()
        for child in children:
            widget = child.GetWindow()
            if isinstance(widget, wx.Button):
                if widget.IsShown():
                    widget.Hide()
                else:
                    widget.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onSort(self, event):
        """
        Sort the buttons
        """
        children = self.mainSizer.GetChildren()
        buttons = []
        for child in children:
            widget = child.GetWindow()
            if isinstance(widget, wx.Button):
                buttons.append(widget)
                self.mainSizer.Detach(widget)

        sortedBtns =  sorted([btn for btn in buttons], key = lambda y: y.GetName())
        # need to prepend them in reverse order to keep the two control buttons on the bottom
        sortedBtns.reverse()
        for btn in sortedBtns:
            self.mainSizer.Prepend(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.Layout()

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test", size=(600,800))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```